# unexpected execution of nested if statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement

This is a part of a cache system in Android. As normal it tries to get `Bitmap` from `memory cache` and if result is `null`, tries `disk cache` and if find related `Bitmap`, add it to `memory cache`:

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String key) {
    Bitmap rendered = memoryCache.get ( key );
    if (rendered == null) {
        rendered = diskCache.getBitmap ( key );
        if (rendered != null) {
            memoryCache.add ( key, rendered );
        }
    }
    return rendered;
}
```

So when `memoryCache.get ( key )` is **not** `null`, the outer `if` and its nested `if` must not execute. But when I suddenly put a breakpoint, saw `memoryCache.add ( key, rendered );` line was executed even when `rendered` was set by `memoryCache.get ( key )`, although `rendered = diskCache.getBitmap ( key );` line was not executed. Am I mistaking or doing some things wrong? I'm using `Android Studio 2.2.2`.

Comment: Did you tried to put some Logs inside if statements, for me sometimes the debugger shows execution of lines without been really executed.

Comment: The code is fine. If it seems like it's executing `memoryCache.add` when the outer `if`'s condition is false, it's probably just a debugger artifact.

Comment: @danypata I did not do that, but during debugging, I do `step into` and it really entered to the process for adding to `memory cache`.

Comment: try to load form diskCache to another Bitmap local variable  like 'Bitmap rendered2 = diskCache.getBitmap ( key );'

Comment: @danypata @T.J. Crowder  I added a `Log`. As you say it was a debugger artifact.

Comment: It depends on IDE and debugger. Code will be running correctly, and it is only IDE's debugger that reaches to those lines. 
It will be good if you can provide IDE information here. @hasanghaforian

Comment: @hasanghaforian change Bitmap rendered = memoryCache. getBitmap ( key ); and try

Comment: @NeeteshBhardwaj I'm using `Android Studio 2.2.2`.

Comment: Did you got the answer ? @hasanghaforian

Comment: @ABDevelopers Yes. As I commented above, I added a Log and it seems to be a debugger artifact.